# Get average image from video

Tags: video, images, colors, pixels

In Ubuntu 10.04, is there a program that I can install (or is pre-installed) that can get the mean color value of each pixel from a video.

The purpose behind this is to see if the result of getting the average image from a set of highly-correlated images looks normal to the human eye.

Comment: I'd rather not program my own, but there seems to be some Java code for this here: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.image/how-to-get-average-of-a-set-of-images.html